# Android XML Textview Bold

Tags: android, xml

Below are my codes, I'm trying to set Bold to my XML file using an XML Parser DOM. Can anyone please tell me how it is done? I just want my "Title :" to be bold.

```
textview.setText(textview.getText() + "<b>Title :</b> " //This line
                            + getValue("title", eElement) + "\n" + "\n");

                    textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Description : "
                            + getValue("description", eElement) + "\n" + "\n");

                    textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Link : "
                            + getValue("link", eElement) + "\n" + "\n");

                    textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Date : "
                            + getValue("date", eElement) + "\n" + "\n" + "\n"
                            + "\n");
```

Comment: You really should consider using a StringBuilder for your strings instead of concatenating them like that...

Comment: do it in the TextView tag in xml: android:textStyle="bold"

Comment: but, doing this will bold everything. I just want my title to be bolded

Comment: @DroidBeginner : try it as : `textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(textview.getText() + "<b>Title :</b> " +getValue("title", eElement) + "<br></br>" + "<br></br>"));`

Comment: @DroidBeginner you should **mention that** in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this ,

```
  textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC); or
  textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

using html,

```
tetview.setText(Html.fromHtml(somestring));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that directly in the `textView` tag
Do this:

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is to tell the textview to convert from HTML.

so change it to textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourtext));

EDIT: If you have Problems with adding the resulting charSequence to your existing text, use:

```
Html.fromHtml(yourtext).toString()
```

You cannot concatinate it simply as you did it, because Html.fromHtml() returns a charSequence, not a String

Setting the style in the layout file will result in ALL the text being bold, italic, wahtsoever